# Apache RewriteRule working in 2.2.3, not working in 1.3.41

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-1.3

I created the following RewriteRule during development of a site on our dev server which runs Apache 2.2.3:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^add-ons/(?!=details|download)(.+) /add-ons/details/$2 [NC]
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is to knock out the /details/ part of the URL so that I can have a link like example.com/add-ons/some-addon/ instead of example.com/add-ons/details/some-addon/.

Unfortunately upon releasing this to the live server, running Apache 1.3.41, I get `Error 500: Internal Server Error`. I've played around with it but nothing I've tried works. Is this a limitation of Apache 1.3, maybe the forward lookahead isn't allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrote it using a RewriteCond instead of the negative lookahead, this seems to work:

```
RewriteCond $0 !^add-ons/(details|download) [NC]
RewriteRule ^add-ons/(.+)$ /add-ons/details/$1 [NC,L]
```